# How do you send input from a form in a webpage to a search bar in a different website?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets use https://www.wolframalpha.com/ as an example. In the website there is a search bar. I want to pass user input from my websites search bar [Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfcPV.png) to the search bar in wolframalpha.com. If a user entered "euler" in my form, I would want the string "Euler" to be sent to Wolframalphas search bar and entered.

I want to avoid the solution of appending the parameter to the destination page's URL because it doesn't work in my particular case.

```
<div>
   <style type="text/css">
       label {
           color: black; font-style: bold; font-size: 20px;
       }

       form.index-search-form {
           position: relative; display: inline-flex;
       }

       input.search-box {
           width: 400px; height: 40px; padding: 2px 0; border-radius: 50px; padding-left: 20px;
       }

       button[name="submit"] {
           position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border-radius: 50px; background: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; background: #e21e2d; color: white; cursor: default; font-size: 16px; width: 180px; height: 40px; outline: none;
       }

       input:focus {
           border-color: #4d90fe; outline: none;
       }

       input.search-box:hover {
           box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); background: #f8f8f8; border: 1px solid #c6c6c6; box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); color: #222;
       }

   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function redirect()
       {

       }

   </script>
   <div class="container">
       <form action="javascript:redirect()" class="index-search-form">
           <label>FIND A CHURCH&nbsp;</label> 
           <input id="search" class="search-box" type="search" maxlength="24" placeholder="Search...">
           <button name="submit" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
       </form>
   </div></div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried before for the `function redirect()` ?

Comment: function redirect() appended the parameter to the destination page's URL but its not what i'm trying to do anymore
 
`function redirect(){
   var searchitem = document.getElementById("search");
   var url = "https://www. =" + searchitem.value;
   window.open(url, "");
  }`